# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController>,<Tab>

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to implement Tabs into my secondView.On button touch(from ViewController.m) I am navigating to secondView(Tabs). In my `Tabs.xib` file I have added a TabBar at bottom and it is custom class of `UITabBar`.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)touchedInside:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"touhced up inside");

    Tabs *temp = [[Tabs alloc]initWithNibName:@"Tabs" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];
    [self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

**Tabs.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
   /* 
    Tab_1 *firstView = [[Tab_1 alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"First" image:nil tag:1];
    [firstView setTabBarItem:item1];
    NSLog(@"after first tab is added");
    Tab_2 *secondView = [[Tab_2 alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sec" image:nil tag:1] ;
    [secondView setTabBarItem:item2];
     NSLog(@"after second tab is added");
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstView,secondView,nil] animated:NO];
     NSLog(@"after tab is added");
    [appDelegate.window  addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    NSLog(@"after view is added");
   */
    appDelegate.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[Tab_1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab 1" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[Tab_2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab 2" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[Tab_2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab 1" bundle:nil];

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, nil];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    Tabs *temp = [[Tabs alloc]initWithNibName:@"Tabs" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:temp animated:NO];

}
```

**Errors**

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController: 0x6833c80>.
2012-12-06 09:57:48.963 demoTabs[667:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Tabs: 0x6a3fc90>.
```

Comment: try setting animated to NO while pushing your view controller.

Comment: @Will, the code is working, but instead of tabs at bottom or either of views, I am getting a complete black-screen

Comment: see the code in answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Tab_1 *viewController1 = [[Tab_1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab 1" bundle:nil];
> Tab_2 *viewController2 = [[Tab_2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab 2" bundle:nil];
> Tab_2 *viewController3 = [[Tab_2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab 1" bundle:nil];
> ```

Define the instance of viewcontroller as above defined, also make sure to give coorect nib file name against each viewcontroller.

Comment: `Unknown class GLKView in Interface Builder file.` and still the same black screen

Comment: I am not sure what GLKView class do, I need to see your project for further solving the problem

Comment: Will,did u download the project ?

Comment: yes, I have downloaded it, but in the way you are doing is wrong, you have add tabbar controller in appdelegate class and present button Viewcontroller with present modeal viewcontroller and on button tap dismiss modal view controller.

Comment: Will, what should be correct approach then ? Please can you correct the project ? an re-upload it